# reference array of folders without variable

Tags: bash, shell

If i can get actual folder as array thanks to:

```
myArray=./*
```

and then I can count elements of this array like this:

```
${#myArray[@]}
```

How can I do it without assign it to a variable? Something like this:

```
${#./*[@]}
```

Comment: The first line doesn't populate an array. Use `myArray=(./*)` instead.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? why not use `ls` and `wc`: `ls  | wc -l`

Comment: Note: both will list all files and directories in your current pwd excluding hidden folders (those starting with `.`)

Comment: @choroba thanks for mentioning, actually i was able to populated an array even with myArray=./* (then loop, count it etc)

Comment: @Nidhoegger thank you for your answer, but i am actually more curious if i can do it this way, than use other commands

Comment: @choroba i don't have any, but yeah you are right, still i'm more curious about the answer than declaration of arrays, thanks :)

Comment: OK, so you are able to assing a value to a normal variable, but are interested in how to get the member count of an array without creating it. I don't understand.

Comment: There are no anonymous arrays in `bash`. You need to create a parameter, *then* use a parameter expansion operator to get its length.

Comment: @chepner if this is true, then it's answer i was looking for. Feel free to post it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` does not have anonymous arrays. You have to create and populate an array variable, *then* apply a parameter expansion operator to it. That said, there are alternatives to using an array; @sorontar provides one that is often feasible.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
set -- ./*;  echo $#
```

The "positional parameters" get changed with the code above.

Or a more reliable version:

```
(shopt -s nullglob; set -- ./*; echo $#)
```